# React Close dropdown when other dropdown is opened

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried but i can't. Do I need to create separate function for each dropdown? I think there should be a brevity. I want other open dropdowns to close when the user clicks on a dropdown. I hope someone can help me. it took me a long time still i couldn't find any result. this way i will add 2 more dropdown menus.

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";

export const AsideItems = () => {
  const [menuOpened, setMenuOpened] = useState(false);
  const [menuOpenedSecond, setMenuOpenedSecond] = useState(false);

  const handleMenu = () => {
    setMenuOpened((menuOpened) => !menuOpened);
  };
  const handleMenuSecond = () => {
    setMenuOpenedSecond((menuOpenedSecond) => !menuOpenedSecond);
  };

  return (
    <>
    <li className="tree-item">
      <a className="tree-link" href="/">
        Computers & Laptops
      </a>
      <span
        onClick={handleMenu}
        className={`list-icon${menuOpened ? " " : " open-list"}`}
      >
        +
      </span>
      <span
        onClick={handleMenu}
        className={`list-icon${menuOpened ? " open-list" : " "}`}
      >
        -
      </span>
      <div className={`sub-menu${menuOpened ? " open-sub" : " "}`}>
        <ul className="sub-nav">
          <li className="sub-item">
            <a href="/" className="sub-link">
              Computer Accessories
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li className="tree-item">
    <a className="tree-link" href="/">
      Game Consoles
    </a>
    <span
      onClick={handleMenuSecond}
      className={`list-icon${menuOpenedSecond ? " " : " open-list"}`}
    >
      +
    </span>
    <span
      onClick={handleMenuSecond}
      className={`list-icon${menuOpenedSecond ? " open-list" : " "}`}
    >
      -
    </span>
    <div className={`sub-menu${menuOpenedSecond ? " open-sub" : " "}`}>
      <ul className="sub-nav">
        <li className="sub-item">
          <a href="/" className="sub-link">
            Consoles
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using multiple boolean state values, you can use a single state value that holds the name (or index) of the open menu. This way you only need one state variable and only one menu can be open at a time. To indicate that no menu is open, you can set the state value to `null`.

Here's an example:

```
const menuNames = {
    first: "first",
    second: "second",
    // ...
}

export const AsideItems = () => {
    const [openMenuName, setOpenMenuName] = React.useState(null);

    return (
        <>
            <span
                onClick={() => setOpenMenuName(menuNames.first)}
                className={`list-icon${openMenuName === menuNames.first ? " " : " open-list"}`}
            >
                +
            </span>
            <span
                onClick={() => setOpenMenuName(menuNames.second)}
                className={`list-icon${openMenuName === menuNames.second ? " " : " open-list"}`}
            >
                +
            </span>
        </>
    )
}
```

Note you don't have to define an object containing the menu names, but it's safer than just using string literals.